# jquery doesn't animate all selected elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple nav with buttons:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="active">
        <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>About</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>Products</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>Reviews</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>Contacts</li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

I select all the  elements after the dom loads:

```
$(document).ready(function){
    // select all a's
    $("ul a").hover(function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity:0.5},250);
    },function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity:1},250);
    })
}
```

My jquery function selects only the first 3 a's and doesn't style the rest on hover. Anyone know what could be wrong? All the a's are positioned relative so I can style them with opacity.

Comment: That's invalid html: the only valid child of a `ul` is an `li` element.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function){` is invalid syntax

Comment: Even if that's invalid html, I am able to make it _work_ on chrome if all `a` are in `display:block`. Maybe you have different `display` value for your `a` elements.

Comment: **well ul>li*5>a and $("ul li").hover() still doesn't select all elements (first 3) so the html isn't the problem**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html structure is wrong. According to [this article](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_a.content), `li` tags are not allowed inside the `<a>` tag.

You should place the `li` directly related to the `ul`:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also, you might want to check your `$(document).ready` sintax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul a").hover(function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity:0.5},250);
    },function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity:1},250);
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37tk4fx6/

**SUGGESTION:**

You should consider using css transitions for that. It is a lot lighter than Jquery. You would solve your problem simply adding:

```
ul a:hover {
    transition: 0.25s;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/37tk4fx6/1/

Comment: turns out even css ul li:hover{}selects only the first 3 elements

Comment: No, it doesn't. Have you checked the fiddle? Also, did you correct your html structure?

Comment: Yes I did you can check the page here: **tomimerachev.com/projects/epickids**

Comment: That is because you have an absolutely positioned image overlying your 4th and 5th `<a>` elements, that is why they are not responding to the mousehover events. The OP's answer is correct, and you should really make your HTML code valid. Also, a functioning fiddle simply tells you that there are **other interfering elements/code on your website**.

Comment: Exactly what @Terry answered. If you must keep this image there, you would have to make your `ul.nav` a `position: relative` at a `z-index` higher than the image's.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is the answer.  I'll clarify the answer.

You have to have wrap your li around your a elements, instead of what you have now.

Then change $('ul a') to $('ul li a').

Or even better to $('ul').find('li').find('a'), which is a huge performance gain for jQuery.